# MS Access query to match keywords in the column

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a key word **Alpha sem1**

but in my database its stored as **MS1 2001090 Alpha sem1**

When i search with **Alpha sem1** i need to check is the given keyword in the column and need to return it

```
select * from Boilers where Orgin ALIKE '%Alpha sem1%'
```

The above query doesn't retrieve the record. how i can achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Orgin` field of a record in `Boilers` contains *MS1 2001090 Alpha sem1*, `select * from Boilers where Orgin ALIKE '%Alpha sem1%'` should return it.  And that should happen regardless of whether the query is run from within or outside an Access application session, and whether the query is run under DAO or ADO/OleDb.

Since you're not getting any rows returned by that query, I wonder about the character(s) between *Alpha* and *sem1*.  Perhaps it resembles a space (ASCII 32), but is actually some other character(s).

See whether you get any rows when you split those target words into 2 conditions.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Boilers
WHERE
        Orgin ALike '%Alpha%'
    AND Orgin ALike '%sem1%'
```

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
Like "*Alpha sem1*"
```

or, if it always in the same position, you could use the MID function to isolate the keyword